# Uploading Image as part of product

Tags: commerce

I am working on a website for a youth organization. They desire to sell sponsorship for organization on site, and we are using Drupal 8.

We are able to create a product and a product variation. We can't find out how to create a field that will accept an end-user submitted image when added to the cart.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: you want  take input  data form user on your product page ?

Comment: Yes amol.  I've got that with the answer below.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Documentation & Background Knowledge is Limited**

It's the truth, we are an organization moving from Ubercart on Drupal 6 to Commerce V2 on Drupal 8.  There's a steeeep learning curve.

So, our situation is that we want local businesses to upload a graphic as part of their sponsorship.  Eventually, we will use this image as part of an advertisement block, but at the moment, our question, HOW do we get this image upload as part of a product.

**Assumptions**

Drupal 8 installed, with Commerce installed V2.

**Steps to Create Upload Field (Image)**

1. Create Order Type - I created an Order Type "Sponsorship".  I used the Default workflow (might have to change in the future).  DONE
2. Create Order Item Types - I created an Order Line Type, named it "Sponsorship", and selected Order Type "Sponsorship".

   1. Then I went to Manage Fields for the Order Item Type "Sponsorship" that I just created and added an Image field to that Order Item Type.
   2. I named the Field "Ad" - as this should be an image uploaded by the sponsor.
3. Product Variation Type - Because I have other products, I wanted a stand along variation for the "Sponsorship".

   1. I created a Product Variation Type - **Advertisement**, as I felt I had used **Sponsorship** too many times.  When I created that **Advertisement** variation, I ensured that I selected **Sponsorship** from the Order types.
   2. I was a bit lost here, but a key point, create the product type variation BEFORE creating the Product Type.
4. Product Type - I then created the **Sponsorship** Product Type, selecting **Advertisement** as the Product Variation.
5. I finally created by product **Front Page Sponsor** and when doing so I selected **Sponsorship** as the Product Type, and completed the balance of the product as normal.

I hope this helps others as well..

Comment: Thanks. Join us on Drupal Slack (#commerce) and share what your main hurdles have been! Perhaps together we can create a documentation guide that maps Ubercart on D6 concepts to Commerce 2.x?